# 2x2 Matrix that is not diagnolizable

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

So I am trying to see if my solution here is adequate or if there is something I may be missing.

Problem:
Find a 2x2 matrix with entries in   $\mathbb{F}_{p}$   that has a power equal to the identity and an eigenvalue in   $\mathbb{F}_{p}$
but is not diagonalizable.

My solution:
The matrix $A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{GL} (2, \mathbb{F}_p)$ where $\mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{3Z}$

Here, A has eigenvalue $1\in \mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{3Z}$. So A is not diagonalizable. Moreover $A^{3}=I_{2}$

Comment: Looks good to me. You might want to explain why the matrix $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: And what if $p \ne 3$? The problem seems to ask for a general prime field, not just the special case $p = 3$ (in this case your solution is correct, but as @SimonS writes, missing explanation)

Comment: @martini is right; you should also generalize to $p$, which is hopefully clear from your example: $A^p = I$.

Comment: So how would I generalize to p?